# GCC Plugin, add new optimizing pragma

Tags: c++, c, gcc, pragma, gcc-plugins

I'm creating a GCC plugin.

I'm trying to create a plugin for a specific loop transformation - unroll loop exactly N (parameter given) times.
I have installed plugins correctly and I can successfully register my pragma in compilation process.
When I register pragma with function `c_register_pragma`, I can handle it in lexical analysis (with function `handle_my_pragma`), but how can I find it then?

I can also define my own pass and traverse GIMPLE, but there is no trace of any pragma.
So my question is: Where is my pragma and how can I influence my code with it?
Or what would you suggest to reach my goal? It doesn't have to be with pragma, but it seemed to be a good idea.
Also, I know about MELT, but within the study of GCC, I would prefer pure plugin in C.

My code

```
static bool looplugin_gate(void)
{
    return true;
}

static unsigned looplugin_exec(void)
{
    printf( "===looplugin_exec===\n" );

    basic_block bb;
    gimple stmt;
    gimple_stmt_iterator gsi;

    FOR_EACH_BB(bb)
    {
        for (gsi=gsi_start_bb(bb); !gsi_end_p(gsi); gsi_next(&gsi), j++)
        {
            stmt = gsi_stmt(gsi);
            print_gimple_stmt (stdout, stmt, 0, TDF_SLIM);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void handle_my_pragma(cpp_reader *ARG_UNUSED(dummy))
{
    printf ("=======Handling loopragma=======\n" );
    enum cpp_ttype token;
    tree x;
    int num = -1;

    token = pragma_lex (&x);
    if (TREE_CODE (x) != INTEGER_CST)
        warning (0, "invalid constant in %<#pragma looppragma%> - ignored"); 
    num = TREE_INT_CST_LOW (x);
    printf( "Detected #pragma loopragma %d\n", num );
}

static void register_my_pragma (void *event_data, void *data)
{
    warning (0, G_("Callback to register pragmas"));
    c_register_pragma (NULL, "loopragma", handle_my_pragma);
}


static struct opt_pass myopt_pass = 
{
    .type = GIMPLE_PASS,
    .name = "LoopPlugin",
    .gate = looplugin_gate,
    .execute = looplugin_exec
};

int plugin_init(struct plugin_name_args   *info,  /* Argument infor */
struct plugin_gcc_version *ver)   /* Version of GCC */
{
const char * plugin_name = info->base_name;
struct register_pass_info pass;

pass.pass = &myopt_pass;
pass.reference_pass_name = "ssa";
pass.ref_pass_instance_number = 1;
pass.pos_op = PASS_POS_INSERT_BEFORE;

register_callback( plugin_name, PLUGIN_PRAGMAS, register_my_pragma, NULL );
register_callback( plugin_name, PLUGIN_PASS_MANAGER_SETUP, NULL, &pass );

return 0;
}
```

PS: If there was someone familiar with GCC plugins development and had a good heart :), please contact me (mbukovy gmail com). I'm doing this because of my final thesis (own choice) and I welcome any soulmate.

Comment: Bingfeng Mei from broadcom had the "pragma unroll" patch for gcc - http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-05/msg00426.html PS what is your GCC version?

Answer (score 3):

> When I register pragma with function c_register_pragma, I can handle it in lexical analysis (with function handle_my_pragma), but how can I find it then?

There is an option (actually, a hack) to create fictive helper function call at the place of pragma, when parsing. Then you can detect this function by name in intermediate representation.

Aslo, several days ago there was a question in GCC ML from  felix.yang (huawei) "How to deliver loop-related pragma information from TREE to RTL?" - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.devel/135243 - check the thread

Some recommendations from the list:

> Look at how we implement #pragma ivdep (see replace_loop_annotate ()
>   and fortran/trans-stmt.c where it builds ANNOTATE_EXPR).

Patch with `replace_loop_annotate()` function addition and `ivdep` pragma implementation: ["Re: Patch: Add #pragma ivdep support to the ME and C FE"](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-10/msg02031.html) by Tobias Burnus (2013-08-24).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! What's about this "hack" for pragma replacement - where do I find something about it? How to use it?

I can't find anything about implementation of pragma ivdep, so this replacement looks usable. Unfortunately, I don't have much time left, so I need to use a quicker way :/

Comment: Michal, there is ivdep patch (googled with "replace_loop_annotate"): http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-10/msg02031.html -- if there was loop with ivdep, in `c_parser_for_statement` the code ` build2 (ANNOTATE_EXPR.. ` is called. There is also text addition to `extend.texi` - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html

Comment: Michal, do you need only "GCC plugin", or patching the gcc's codebase is permitted for you?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid patching. Please, could you show me the way I can replace pragma with function?
Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think registering a DEFERRED pragma in plugin is possible, since the handler for deferred pragma is not exposed in GCC plugin level.

So your pragma just works during preprocessing stage instead of parsing stage, then, it is quite tricky to achieve an optimization goal.